# PHP sum two different minutes

Tags: php, datetime, time, datetime-format

i have two different break time

1. default break time
2. extra break time

here i want to sum of two times and display 12 hrs format

EX :

```
$default_time = "00:30";
 $extra_time   = "00:25";
```

my expected output : **00:55**

but now display **01:00**

this is my code

```
$default_time = $work_data->break_time;
$break_time =  $work_data->extra_time;
$total_break = strtotime($default_time)+strtotime($break_time);
echo date("h:i",strtotime($total_break));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function you can calculate total time by passing the arguments to functions.

$hours, $min are supposed variable which is zero

```
$default_time = "00:30";
$break_time   = "00:25";
function calculate_total_time() {
    $i = 0;
    foreach(func_get_args() as $time) {
        sscanf($time, '%d:%d', $hour, $min);
        $i += $hour * 60 + $min;
    }

    if( $h = floor($i / 60) ) {
        $i %= 60;
    }

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $i);
}

// use example
echo calculate_total_time($default_time, $break_time); # 00:55
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $time = "00:30";
    $time2 = "00:25";

    $secs = strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
    $result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($time)+$secs);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: i want to know what is the logic behind strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00:00")

Answer (score 0):

There is one function call to `strtotime` function too much.

You should leave out the `strtotime()` call in the last line, as `$total_break` already is a UNIX timestamp:

```
$total_break = strtotime($default_time)+strtotime($break_time);
echo date("h:i",$total_break);
```

Comment: if i remove strtotime() in echo output is **03:26**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to add too specific timestamps, but what you're trying to achieve is adding two durations. So you need to convert those timestamps into durations. For that you need a base, which in your case is 00:00.

```
$base = strtotime("00:00");

$default_time = $work_data->break_time;
$default_timestamp = strtotime($default_time);
$default_duration = $default_timestamp - $base; // Duration in seconds

$break_time =  $work_data->extra_time;
$break_timestamp = strtotime($break_time);
$break_duration = $break_timestamp - $base; // Duration in seconds

$total_break = $default_duration + $break_duration; // 55 min in seconds

// If you want to calculate the timestamp 00:55, just add the base back to it
echo date("H:i", $base + $total_break);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using standard `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes. All you will need is to convert your second variable value to `interval_spec` format (see http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php for details):

```
$defaultTime = "00:30";
$breakTime = "PT00H25M"; // Or just 'PT25M'

$totalBreak = (new DateTime($defaultTime))->add($breakTime);
echo $totalBreak->format('H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code fragment:

```
$time1 = explode(":", $default_time);
$time2 = explode(":", $break_time);
$fulltime = ($time1[0] + $time2[0]) * 60 + $time1[1] + $time2[1];
echo (int)($fulltime / 60) . ":" . ($fulltime % 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code you will definitely get your answers.

```
$default_time = "00:30:00";
$extra_time = "00:25:00";

$secs = strtotime($extra_time)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s A",strtotime($default_time)+$secs);
echo $result;die;
```

You can modify above code as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
$default_time = $work_data->break_time;
$date_start = new DateTime($default_time);
$break_time =  $work_data->extra_time;
$interval = new DateInterval("PT" . str_replace(":", "H", $break_time) . "M");
$date_end = $date_start->add($interval);
echo $date_end->format("H:i");
```

Note that this doesn't account for times which span a 24 hour period